# Github action gradle build cannot create application properties file in jar file

Tags: java, spring, docker, gradle, github-actions

I'm building CI/CD using Spring Boot, gradle, GitHub Actions, Docker, AWS.

application properties is separate (application-dev.properties, application-prod.properties) and generates files in GitHub-Actions like that

```
    ## make application-dev.properties
    - name: make application-dev.properties
      if: contains(github.ref, 'feature/#125-CICD')
      run: |
        echo "ls -a . & pwd"
        pwd
        ls -a .

        echo "mkdir & touch"
        mkdir -p ./src/main/resource
        cd ./src/main/resource
        touch ./application-dev.properties
        pwd
        ls -a .

        echo "copy properties"
        echo $DEV_PROP >> ./application-dev.properties
        cat application-dev.properties
      shell: bash
      env:
        DEV_PROP: ${{ secrets.PROPERTIES_DEV }}
```

It's working fine and created file
[image]

next, after build with gradle, when i extracted the jar file after building the gradle and checked it, the properties file does not exist.

check jar file code like that

```
    ## check jar file
    - name: check jar file
      if: contains(github.ref, 'feature/#125-CICD')
      run: |
          pwd
          ls -a .
          cd ./build/libs
          ls -a .
          jar xvf Web-Team-2-Backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
          ls -a .
          cd ./BOOT-INF/classes
          pwd
          ls -a .
      shell: bash
```

[image]

If you check the result, the application-dev.properties file created before does not exist...

What's the problem?
the full code is as follows:

```
name: CI/CD

# event trigger
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - develop
      - feature/#125-CICD

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  CI-CD:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

    ## jdk setting
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin' # https://github.com/actions/setup-java

    ## gradle caching
    - name: Gradle Caching
      uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        path: |
          ~/.gradle/caches
          ~/.gradle/wrapper
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle*', '**/gradle-wrapper.properties') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-

    ## make application-dev.properties
    - name: make application-dev.properties
      if: contains(github.ref, 'feature/#125-CICD')
      run: |
        echo "ls -a . & pwd"
        pwd
        ls -a .

        echo "mkdir & touch"
        mkdir -p ./src/main/resource
        cd ./src/main/resource
        touch ./application-dev.properties
        pwd
        ls -a .

        echo "copy properties"
        echo $DEV_PROP >> ./application-dev.properties
        cat application-dev.properties
      shell: bash
      env:
        DEV_PROP: ${{ secrets.PROPERTIES_DEV }}

    ## gradle build
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew build -x test -x ktlintCheck -x ktlintTestSourceSetCheck -x ktlintMainSourceSetCheck -x ktlintKotlinScriptCheck

    ## check jar file
    - name: check jar file
      if: contains(github.ref, 'feature/#125-CICD')
      run: |
          pwd
          ls -a .
          cd ./build/libs
          ls -a .
          jar xvf Web-Team-2-Backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
          ls -a .
          cd ./BOOT-INF/classes
          pwd
          ls -a .
      shell: bash
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem..

path is resources, not resource :(

```
    ## make application-dev.properties
    - name: make application-dev.properties
      if: contains(github.ref, 'feature/#125-CICD')
      run: |
        echo "ls -a . & pwd"
        pwd
        ls -a .

        echo "mkdir & touch"
        mkdir -p ./src/main/resource << here !!
        cd ./src/main/resource
        touch ./application-dev.properties
        pwd
        ls -a .

        echo "copy properties"
        echo $DEV_PROP >> ./application-dev.properties
        cat application-dev.properties
      shell: bash
      env:
        DEV_PROP: ${{ secrets.PROPERTIES_DEV }}
```